# How to create a Vagrant box from running debian server

Tags: debian, vagrant

can somebody tell me how I can create a vagrant base box from my running Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze) server for testing purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can either manually create a vagrant base box by following the [packaging docs](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html)

or use Veewee to automate the build (you will need to run VirtualBox GUI)

Requirements on the Debian Server

- X11 Desktop Environment or WM
- VirtualBox
- Ruby
- Vagrant
- Veewee

You can use the existing Veewee templates (definitions - customizable) to build vagrant base boxes, refere to [Veewee docs](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/blob/master/doc/basics.md)

If you just want to use and destroy, grab the pre-built vagrant base boxes from [vagrantbox.es](http://vagrantbox.es) or Opscode [bento](https://github.com/opscode/bento)

Comment: I don't get it. Why do I need the desktop environment / window manager on the server? Is my question wrong? I want to have an vagrant box that is created with the same content/configuration as the debian server. I want to be able to try out software without interfering with the running server.

Comment: If you use veewee, it'll use VirtualBox GUI + Kickstart to automate the build. I haven't looked into see if there is an option to bypass VirtualBox GUI like vagrant.